# cannot read yahoo xml feed in php

Tags: php, xml, yahoo

i am trying to read the yahoo rss (http://news.yahoo.com/rss/us) in php using the xml function

this is myvery simple code:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');
 var_dump($xml['channel']);
```

but i shows **NULL**:

```
adam@cka: php test.php
NULL
```

is my XML broken? or there's a better function in php to read xml file?

i can see the elment exists in the XML file and i downloaded the file correctly in my computer.

Comment: [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) return an object not an array: `Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the XML document, or FALSE on failure.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SimpleXML returns an object, not an array. Try this:

```
<?php
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://news.yahoo.com/rss/us');
 var_dump($xml->channel);
?>
```

Comment: oh it works, is it mean i can't use array? like [] and not ->

Comment: If you prefer to use arrays you can typecast with `$xml = (array)$xml;` after the simplexml call.

Comment: i like that - thanks i will use this much easier than the other thing

Comment: Great! If that answered your question please tick it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://news.yahoo.com/rss/us');

echo $rss->channel->title;

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
   echo $item->link. " -- " .$item->title;
   echo $item->pubDate;
   echo $item->description;
}
```

Comment: i get this: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/rss.php on line 7

Comment: ok removed all quotes, can you chekc it once, this is working for me